# How to sum all the elements of a numpy object array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have an a numpy object array that is made up of several normal numpy arrays

```py
>> a = np.array([np.arange(5), np.arange(2), np.arange(7)])
>> a
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

And I want to sum all the elements, and that should ideally give me `32`. If I use `sum(a)` I get an error. However, I can get a result using

```py
>> sum([np.sum(array) for array in a])
32
```

But I was wondering if there is any faster/simpler way to do this?

Comment: No this is pretty good, you are using the python built-in sum to sum up the bigger list, which comprises of the sums of the `np.arange` lists, and you are using `np.sum` to sum up the individual numpy arrays!

Comment: If your code works but you want to improve it, post on codereview

Comment: You can remove the square brackets in `sum` if you want.  `sum(np.sum(array) for array in a)`

Comment: @alec_a, questions like this are commonly answered by the SO `numpy` community.  CR has fewer `numpy` eyes, and tends to focus more on good programming style.

Comment: `sum(a)` tries to do `a[0]+a[1]+a[2]`, and complains about adding a 5 element array to a 2 element one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
print (np.concatenate(a).sum())
```

---

```
print (np.sum(np.concatenate(a)))
32
```

**Performance**: Depends of number of nested arrays and number of values in arrays, so best test in real data:

```
a = np.array([np.arange(5), np.arange(2), np.arange(7)] * 1000) 
#print (a)

In [40]: %timeit np.concatenate(a).sum()
830 µs ± 22.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [41]: %timeit (np.sum(np.concatenate(a)))
835 µs ± 33.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#original solution 
In [42]: %timeit sum([np.sum(array) for array in a])
15.3 ms ± 85.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Another solutions:

```
In [43]: %timeit sum(np.sum(array) for array in a)
17.4 ms ± 2.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit (sum(np.concatenate(a)))
2.28 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: +1 for the performance analysis. If I get your analysis correctly, the important factors are firstly to use `np.sum` and not `sum`, and secondly to concatenate the array `a` rather than loop on it?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - yes, in numpy is faster use numpy function like python functions, because vectorized. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While your code is good, you can also use [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to concatenate your arrays and then calcuate the sum via [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), python builtin [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), or a `sum` function over the numpy array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.arange(5), np.arange(2), np.arange(7)])

print(np.sum(np.concatenate(a)))
#32

print(sum(np.concatenate(a)))
#32

print(np.concatenate(a).sum())
#32
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
>>> sum(map(sum,a))
32
```